# Compare the results of 2 queries that have "ORDER BY" in PostgreSQL to check for match and mismatch

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, sorting, compare

I am writing a small app that mark students' queries in PostgreSQL against the teacher's queries. For normal query I can easily use EXCEPT and UNION to find the mismatches. But how can I check the ones that need sorting.

If the answer matches all rows but only part of it are in right order. How can find the number of sorted rows and mark the case properly?

My program is written in Python with Psycopg2 library.

Comment: (1) What database are you using, MySQL or Postgres?  (2) You are more likely to get an answer to a single question, not to a panoply of them.

Comment: The database is Postgres

Answer (score 1):

You can compare both queries joined by `row_number()`. Example:

```
create table example (id int, str text);
insert into example values (1, 'alfa'), (2, 'beta');

with teacher as ( -- teachers query
    select * from example order by id
    ),
student as (      -- students query
    select * from example order by id desc
    ),
teacher_rn as (
    select row_number() over () rn, *
    from teacher
    ),
student_rn as (
    select row_number() over () rn, *
    from student
    )
select t.*, s.*
from teacher_rn t
join student_rn s
on t.rn = s.rn
where t <> s;

 rn | id | str  | rn | id | str  
----+----+------+----+----+------
  1 |  1 | alfa |  1 |  2 | beta
  2 |  2 | beta |  2 |  1 | alfa
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks. But if there is any row that does not match the rn, all the rows after it will be affected. Is there any way to do it like a merge join where that row will be removed and the rows after it are checked normally. I need to count the number of rows that does not match.